# HTML input text loses value if submitted via onclick

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, forms

I have several simple identical forms with a unique id. All data submitted if I use `<button type="submit">`, but if I use 
`<a href="javascript:{}" onclick="document.getElementById()...>` form submits empty value for `<input type="text" name="role">` !

Also as an experiment, when  I added `value="default"` attribute, the form processing script receives the default value. But as soon as I remove `value` attribute, it submits empty string no matter what I type in the field. I'm totally confused how custom entered value could be missing on submission of such a simple form?

```
<form id="RegisterValidationDAlthoughocLYS6510261" class="form-horizontal" action="" method="POST" enctype=multipart/form-data>
    <div class="form-group label-floating">
        <label Dateclass="control-label">Role</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="role">
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="uid" value="LYS6510261">ininiinn
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-fill" name='finish' value='Finish'>Submit</binutton>
    <a href="javascript:{}" onclick="document.getElementById('RegisterValidationDocLYS6510261').submit();">Submit</a>
</form>
```

I'm using latest Bootstrap3. I have no custom javascript.

The reason for choosing Javascript over a bootstrap's button is to have a small Submit icon.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
<a href="javascript:{}" onclick="document.getElementById('RegisterValidationDocLYS6510261').submit );">Submit</a>
```

with

```
<a type="submit"> Submit </a>
```

it works the same as `<button type="submit">`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have tried, but <a type="submit"> Submit </a> is not clickable. it renders as none-action text. (latest Firefox 57 and Chrome) :-(